# Invisible/visible submit button in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have table with 2 rows. The rows contains a text box and a submit button.

Question:

When the user clicks the text box then the submit button should be visible.How can I do it.
I tried using the closest function but it does not work.

HTML Code

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="submit" value="validate" style="display:none"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="submit" value="validate" style="display:none"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

JQuery

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $( "#table1" ).on( "click", "input:text", function( event ) {
        var parent = $(this).closest('td').show();
        alert('Clicked')
    })
```

})

http://jsfiddle.net/92HHG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You can use `closest()` to target *td* then navigate to next *td* and the find *submit* button

```
$(this).closest('td').next('td').find(':submit').show();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/92HHG/2/)

OR

Here You can use `closest()` to target *tr* then find *submit* button

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(':submit').show();
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/92HHG/4/)

Comment: This one works but when I click the next text box the first one is still visible. It should not be shown...I tried $(this).closest('table').find(':submit').not(this).hide(); but it does not work

Comment: @user1050619, Heres solution http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/92HHG/7/ Just find all _submit_ button and hide them before you display current one

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $( "#table1" ).on( "click", "input:text", function( event ) {
           $('input[type=submit]').hide();
           $button =  $(this).parent().next().find('input');

           $button.show();


        })

})
```

It is the best solution :D

Answer (score 0):

One approach is `$(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').find('[type=submit]').show();`

It finds the first parent `tr` of the text box, then find the child submit.

Or you can do `$(this).parent().next()` to get the next td

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=submit]").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach, to be responsive to those who don't like tables for layout.
And just a different approach about "showing" the buttons.

I've used ".blur", but you would use .focus, .click, whatever you want.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/92HHG/6/)

HTML

```
<div class='holderdiv'>
  <div><input id='upperin' type="text"/><input type="submit" value="Validate" id='upperbutton'/></div>
  <div><input id='lowerin' type="text"/><input type="submit" value="Validate" id='lowerbutton'/></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#upperin').blur(function(){
       $('#upperbutton').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
$('#lowerin').blur(function(){
       $('#lowerbutton').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```